# What is the actual root of this particular error code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to discover what the source of the ambiguity is, and cannot figure out how to find out which two possible call signatures this could be from:

> Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DisplayLib.Extensions.FormExtensions.ShowTopmostWithoutFocus(System.Windows.Forms.Form)' and 'DisplayLib.Extensions.FormExtensions.ShowTopmostWithoutFocus(System.Windows.Forms.Form)'

Double clicking on the code itself brings me to one possible definition, i cannot locate the other.

In the event I am able to locate the source of the ambiguity, what are my options for solving it?

This is using visual studio 2022, and the codebase is csharp.   Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are somehow referencing two (different or identical) copies of the same library, either though NuGet or through a direct .dll link, or - who knows - through a combination of both. Just guessing at this point... but I recommend to check & double check both your project references and your linked packages.

Comment: Possibly referenceing the library twice, different versions?

Comment: Let us assume for a moment I was referencing a library twice - would that necessarily be through the references section of one of the projects?  I don't see how it could be through nuget, the only things added through the package manager were addons for syntax enforcement.   I'm a bit new to csharp, my experience is with c++.